# How exactly does htaccess interact with my php script?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess script:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([A-Z0-9-]+)\.stage-proxy\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/%1.com/$1 [L]
```

and so when I browse to

```
http://google.stage-proxy.com/analytics
```

according to http://htaccess.madewithlove.be, the inbound URL should be

```
http://google.stage-proxy.com/index.php/google.com/analytics
```

But whenever I try to browse my $_SERVER variables in php it still comes up as

```
http://google.stage-proxy.com/analytics
```

I know that htaccess is enabled (I know the mod_rewrite module is installed, and allowOverride All is on).  What's going on?  Do I have some glaring hole in my .htaccess knowledge?

For reference, I'm using ubuntu server 13.04.  Not sure if that really would change anything though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why your rules aren't looping, it should cause a 500 internal error without something like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` to prevent the looping.

Anyways, the `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` should be `/index.php/google.com/analytics` from **index.php**, or you can check `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO]`.

The [$_SERVER documentation says](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

> **PHP_SELF**: The filename of the currently executing script, relative to the document root. For instance, $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] in a script at the address `http://example.com/test.php/foo.bar` would be `/test.php/foo.bar`. The **FILE** constant contains the full path and filename of the current (i.e. included) file. If PHP is running as a command-line processor this variable contains the script name since PHP 4.3.0. Previously it was not available.

and

> **PATH_INFO**: Contains any client-provided pathname information trailing the actual script filename but preceding the query string, if available. For instance, if the current script was accessed via the URL `http://www.example.com/php/path_info.php/some/stuff?foo=bar`, then `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` would contain `/some/stuff`.